# MySQL Query Needs Optimization?

Tags: mysql

I have a couple of queries that serve their purposes but since I'm not an expert and just dabble here and there, I'm wondering if these queries can be optimized.

I'm asking because it seems that as more records are added, the time it takes for the queries to complete also seem to increase.

1. ```
   SELECT u.`UserId`, u.`GroupId`, u.`MemberType`, g.`GroupLevel`, g.`U`, g.`D`, 
   (SELECT COUNT(u2.`UserId`) FROM `users` u2 
   INNER JOIN `groups` g2 ON g2.`Active` = 1 AND u2.`UserId` = g2.`UserId` 
   WHERE u2.`Level` = '$L_MEMBER' 
   AND u2.`MemberType` = '$M_Type' 
   AND u2.`CounUserId` = u.`UserId` 
   AND u2.`Active` = 1 
   AND g2.`U` > g.`U` 
   AND g2.`D` < g.`D`) as UsersGroup 
   FROM `users` u 
   INNER JOIN `groups` g ON g.`UserId` = u.`UserId` AND g.`Active` 
   WHERE u.`Level` = '$L_MEMBER' AND u.`DateCreated` < '$subdate' AND u.`Active` = 1 
   ORDER BY u.`UserId`
   ```
2. ```
   SELECT g.`UserId` FROM `groups` g 
   WHERE g.`U` BETWEEN '$U' AND '$D' 
   AND g.`UserId` !=0 
   AND g.`UserId` NOT IN (SELECT da.`TaggedUserId` as UserId FROM `dateawarded` da WHERE da.`UserId` = '$userid' AND `DateTagged` != '$datetagged') 
   AND g.`UserId` NOT IN (SELECT u.`UserId` FROM `users` u WHERE u.`Membership` <= '1') 
   AND g.`UserId` NOT IN (SELECT d.`DemotedUserId` FROM `demoted` d WHERE d.`UserId` = '$userid' AND d.`DateDemoted` < '$datetagged 00:00:00') 
   AND g.`DateModified` < '$thedate'
   ```

EXPLAIN Results:

Query 1:

```
1   PRIMARY             g   ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL                18747   Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort    
1   PRIMARY             u   eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4       user_db.g.UserId        1   Using where 
2   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  g2  ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL                18747   Using where 
2   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  u2  eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4       user_db.g2.UserId       1   Using where
```

Query 2:

```
1   PRIMARY     g   ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    18747   Using where
4   SUBQUERY    d   ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    6895    Using where
3   SUBQUERY    u   ALL PRIMARY NULL    NULL    NULL    9354    Using where
2   SUBQUERY    da  ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    39260   Using where
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, as @Mawg asks, how long is the query taking? Also, how many records in each table? Also, what do your indexes look like? But at a glance, I'm going to go on a limb and say the 3 subqueries are your issue.

Comment: show output from `EXPLAIN [query]` for both queries

Comment: @Lucas Right now, at 10,000 records, it's taking about 2 hours to complete.

Comment: @Raymond I will post the EXPLAIN output

Comment: Can you explain the g.active bit?

Comment: A compound index on userid,level,datecreated,active seems like a good idea, but without SHOW CREATE TABLES and the EXPLAIN for the given queries, it's hard to say further.

Comment: @Strawberry Some accounts are deactivated and flagged as such. The g.`Active` makes sure that only active records are included in the results.

Comment: @Strawberry EXPLAIN output added.

Comment: i specifically meant the line `INNER JOIN groups g ON g.UserId = u.UserId AND g.Active`

Comment: @Strawberry Can I do without it? That line is there so I can get everyone above (g.U) the user and below (g.D)the user that are in the same User Group (g2.`U` > g.`U` 
AND g2.`D` < g.`D`).

Comment: Except where g.active is 0 `AND g.Active` is always true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To optimize the first query, add these indexes:

```
ALTER TABLE `groups` ADD INDEX `groups_idx_userid_grouple_u_d` (`UserId`, `GroupLevel`, `U`, `D`);
ALTER TABLE `groups` ADD INDEX `groups_idx_active_userid_u` (`Active`, `UserId`, `U`);
ALTER TABLE `users` ADD INDEX `users_idx_level_activ_useri_datec_group_membe` ( `Level`, `Active`, `UserId`, `DateCreated`, `GroupId`, `MemberType` );
ALTER TABLE `users` ADD INDEX `users_idx_level_member_active_userid_counus` ( `Level`, `MemberType`, `Active`, `UserId`, `CounUserId` );
```

To optimize the second query, add these indexes:

```
ALTER TABLE `dateawarded` ADD INDEX `dateawarded_idx_userid_datetagged_taggeduser` (`UserId`, `DateTagged`, `TaggedUserId`);
ALTER TABLE `demoted` ADD INDEX `demoted_idx_userid_datedemote_demoteduse` (`UserId`, `DateDemoted`, `DemotedUserId`);
ALTER TABLE `groups` ADD INDEX `groups_idx_u_userid` (`U`, `UserId`);
ALTER TABLE `users` ADD INDEX `users_idx_membership_userid` (`Membership`, `UserId`);
```

Comment: Will try this and provide feedback. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for this Tomer! Worked like a charm. Processing 9,000+ records used to take and hour and a half but with the indexes in place, it now only takes 20-30 minutes. If it's alright with you, can you let me know the basis for the indexes your provided? So that I can implement them on my own next time. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, glad I could help. You can optimize the query and indexes automatically with [EverSQL](https://www.eversql.com). The indexes I suggested here came directly from there (disclaimer: I'm a co-founder at EverSQL). Let me know if there is anything else I can do to assist. If you prefer to do it manually, the [basics of indexes](https://www.eversql.com/choosing-the-best-indexes-for-mysql-query-optimization/) can be found in this blog post.

Comment: Cool! Will have a look as I have a couple or so more queries that need to be optimized...

Answer (score 0):

Did you profile these queries, to see how long they take to run?

Then add more (dummy test) data & see how much longer they take & decide if that is acceptable?

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/show-profile.html for details.

You will get output something like this

> mysql> SHOW PROFILE;
>   +----------------------+----------+
>   | Status               | Duration |
>   +----------------------+----------+
>   | checking permissions | 0.000040 |
>   | creating table       | 0.000056 |
>   | After create         | 0.011363 |
>   | query end            | 0.000375 | 
>   | freeing items        | 0.000089 |
>   | logging slow query   | 0.000019 |
>   | cleaning up          | 0.000005 |
>   +----------------------+----------+
>    7 rows in set (0.00 sec)

Only you can decide what is an acceptable time for the query to run.

---

[Udpdate] I only posted an answer as this was too large for a comment. @Raymond is correct to say that `EXPLAIN [query]` will be very helpful

Comment: Up until 5,000+ records, it only took 30 minutes which is pretty acceptable. But now it takes almost 2 hours so I'm thinking something is wrong.